# AWS Classic Load Balancer End-to-End Encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer

Is it possible to configure an AWS Classic Balancer to do something like this:

Client  <-- SSL (Signed Certificate) --> ELB <-- SSL (Self-Signed Certificate) --> EC2

Looking at listener configurations, it looks like there is a one to one relationship between the listener and the certificate it uses.

If anyone knows how I could achieve this, being pointed to some documentation would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can create a load balancer that listens on both the HTTP (80) and
>   HTTPS (443) ports. If you specify that the HTTPS listener sends
>   requests to the instances on port 80, the load balancer terminates the
>   requests and communication from the load balancer to the instances is
>   not encrypted. If the HTTPS listener sends requests to the instances
>   on port 443, communication from the load balancer to the instances is
>   encrypted.

[Create a Classic Load Balancer with an HTTPS Listener](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html)

Comment: That is how I've currently configured things. However what I'm asking is it possible to use a Classic Load Balancer to terminate ssl when it receives a request and then use a different certificate to encrypt connection between itself and an EC2 instance. "If the HTTPS listener sends requests to the instances on port 443, communication from the load balancer to the instances is encrypted." - Encrypted how? I can't find any info on that. (edit: does it use Amazon Public Key Infrastructure to achieve this?)

Comment: The communications between the ELB and the EC2 instance is encrypted using the certificate that you installed on the EC2 instance. In exactly the same way as a web browser communicates with a web instance using SSL (TLS). In ELB -> EC2 the ELB is the client, the EC2 is the server.

Comment: So it isn't possible to do what I asked above? As you can only configure a listener with a single certificate with a Classic Load Balancer?

Comment: The answer is no. The HTTP protocol for web servers does not support what you are suggesting. There is the case of client authentication, where the client also provides its certificate to the web server (for authentication), but this is not supported by ELB.

Comment: @Jesse I'm not convinced that the two of you are having the same conversation.  Yes, you can do what is depicted above.  The listener doesn't need a certificate facing the instance, just like the web browser doesn't need a certificate.  If the listener is configured for HTTPS toward the instance, the traffic inside is encrypted, with SSL negotiated between balancer and instance using the instance's cert.  You can also [require that the back-end use the right cert](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html#configure_backendauth_clt).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot. You may be right, but in the comments portion, I am under the impression that Jesse wants to install another certificate on the ELB listener to encrypt between ELB and EC2. My comments are that the certificate is installed on EC2 in typical server mode.

Comment: Yes, and what you are saying is correct -- when the listener is configured for SSL on the back-side, that's end-to-end encryption.  The front-side cert is not used on the back-side, since ELB is the client and needs no certificate.  I suspect that the confusion arises from associating the certificate with the listener being interpreted as somehow facing both directions, when it only faces outward.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you are 100% correct with my confusion (I thought listener would be configured both directions with the same cert), you have cleared this up for me, thank you!